# Is it a best practice to keep enums mirrored in the database as a form of documentation?

Tags: database-design, language-agnostic

I have an enum in code

```
enum EventType
{
     Run = 1,
     Stop = 2,
}
```

I have a table in my database

```
CREATE TABLE [Event] (
    [Id] integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    [EventType] integer NOT NULL,
    [Timestamp] text NOT NULL
);
```

Should I, if I don't really need to?

```
CREATE TABLE [EventType] (
    [EventTypeId] integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    [Name] text
);
INSERT INTO "EventType" VALUES(1, "Run");
INSERT INTO "EventType" VALUES(2, "Stop");
```

This is bad because it's code duplication. It's good because it is a documentation for those who access the database and wonder what those EventType numbers mean. Should I drop these numbers altogether and use strings instead?

Comment: Well, one benefit beyond simple documentation would be that if/when you ever try to access the DB from another system you then have a way of generating known-correct enums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not create extra table just for the sake of documenting things. It increases overall complexity and therefore  make it worse long term than having users wonder what those numbers are.

I, personally, like using string enums in DB exactly because it makes it self documenting. There could be different opinions, though.

Comment: What are string enums? Is that a database specific feature? I'm working with SQLite...

Comment: I meant use string values stored in the database instead of numbers as, I understood, you are considering.